# Working at two labs vs having two advisors in grad school?

Tags: graduate-school, computer-science, research-assistantship, lab-management

There are two labs that I really want to work as a masters student research assistant but I know that grad school isn't like undergrad and working for two will probably drive me crazy. One is in the field of human-computer interaction and the other one is in computer vision. So I thought of instead of working for two, I was thinking working as a masters thesis student for Human-Computer Interaction Lab and hopefully have professor from computer vision lab as a secondary advisor. Can anyone advise me on this situation?

Comment: "grad school isn't like undergrad and working for two will probably drive me crazy."
you could not be more wrong: working for two labs will drive you crazy irrespective of your graduation status.

Comment: I worked at two different research lab during undergrad and it didn't drive me crazy. One was primary and the other secondary. So I'm not wrong. You are.